# Deleted config.xml when Jenkins server was running

Tags: xml, jenkins

I deleted **`"config.xml"`** file in the Jenkins source folder when Jenkins was running.
 When I restarted Jenkins service, it gives **Error**:

```
Cannot read config.xml
```

The config files for all the jobs running are there.
Is there any way through which I can start Jenkins and configure it again ?

Comment: restore config.xml from your last backup.

Comment: @DonRoby Haven't taken a backup yet..

Comment: Try creating an empty config.xml, and restart Jenkins

Answer (score 4):

All you need is to create a config.xml in JENKINS_HOME directory with below 3 elements in it:

- VERSION
- WORKSPACE DIRECTORY
- BUILDS DIRECTORY

I have tested this in my Jenkins instance.

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<hudson>
  <version>1.581</version>
  <workspaceDir>${JENKINS_HOME}/workspace/${ITEM_FULLNAME}</workspaceDir>
  <buildsDir>${ITEM_ROOTDIR}/builds</buildsDir>
</hudson>
```

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins keeps a history of the configuration, so you should be able to recover your deleted file from /var/lib/jenkins/config-history/[backup date folder]

Comment: @p-ntende This is what i am looking for thanks for saving lots of time.