# Config.xml in jenkins -how to replace it with a right file?

Tags: xml, jenkins, continuous-integration, config

' access was denied'  in jenkins and I tried to change somethings in the config.xml file ,I get different errors everytime and now that I have changed so many things of  the file i would like to know if there any way I could have a fresh config.xml file or should I re-install jenkins all over again to get back on feet 
 Thanks

Comment: Check my suggestion for restoring to original config.xml at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27797727/deleted-config-xml-when-jenkins-server-was-running/52799249#52799249

Answer (score 2):

Download .war File from https://jenkins.io/download/ and replace your config.xml with the config.xml from inside the .war File

Comment: This is a better answer.

Comment: @mrkernelpanic I cant get java -jar jenkins.war to run without error i tried renaming it to .zip and extracting but i did not find any xml file in it

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a backup copy, you can probably remove the config.xml and replace it with the following:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<hudson>
  <version>1.581</version>
  <workspaceDir>${JENKINS_HOME}/workspace/${ITEM_FULLNAME}</workspaceDir>
  <buildsDir>${ITEM_ROOTDIR}/builds</buildsDir>
</hudson>
```

That will reset all the global settings. I think it will keep your jobs intact, but I've never tried this before.

Comment: Hi thank you but I am back with a unsecured mode . How could I have a login for my username and password as I did before thanks!